# Accessing rails path from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, get

I'm trying to access the "next" method in my Rails controller from within a javascript file. From what I've read, it seems like I actually need to turn my js into a js.erb file, and reference the path with "asset_path." However, I keep getting an error message in my console saying "Invalid regular expression: missing /" that points to the line of code where I have:

```
$.get(<%= asset_path('next') %>, {id: projectId, next: 4}).done(function(response){
```

Basically, I'm just trying to access the method "def next" in one of my controllers. Is there an easier way?? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right you erb file is getting compiled to

```
$.get(/some/path/here, {id: projectId, next: 4}).done(function(response)
```

So to fix it wrap it in quotes

$.get("<%= asset_path('next') %>", {id: projectId, next: 4}).done(function(response)

which should get rendered to

```
$.get("/some/path/here", {id: projectId, next: 4}).done(function(response)
```

Comment: OK, interesting. My "next" method is in my Projects controller, so I wrote: $.get("<%= asset_path('projects/next') %>" and am now getting a 500 error message-- looks like some issue within the view...but to access that route, did I have it right with "projects/next?"

Comment: it looks like the [helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path) prefixes `assets` if you use relative link. so `asset_path('projects/next') ` resolves to `/assets/projects/next` and `asset_path('/projects/next')` resolves to `/projects/next`

Answer (score 0):

`<%= asset_path('next') %>` won't link to a line of code, that helper is usually for linking to assets like CSS, JS files or Images.

The way I usually pass a link to javascript from a view is by using data attributes on the html for example:

view.html.erb

```
<div id="someId" data-somedata="<%= @information_I_want_to_pass %>">
</div>
```

Then in my javascript file I use jquery to get the information:

javascript.js

```
function example(){
   var url = $('#somId').data('somedata');
   $.get(url, {id: projectId, next: 4})
    .done(function(response)
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: i agree, passing data from view to js, should be the best way.

Comment: Thanks! That does help.